# Pivot tabla mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, pivot

Hola tengo una tabla en MYSQL con la siguiente estructura:

```
   +------------+------------+---------+
   |   fecha    | zona_carga |   pml   |
   +------------+------------+---------+
   | 2021-01-01 |  Acapulco  |    10   |
   +------------+------------+---------+
   | 2021-01-02 |  Acapulco  |    13   |
   +------------+------------+---------+
   | 2021-01-03 |  Acapulco  |    15   |
   +------------+------------+---------+
   | 2021-01-04 |  Acapulco  |    66   |
   +------------+------------+---------+
   | 2021-01-05 |  Acapulco  |    10   |
   +------------+------------+---------+
   | 2021-01-06 |  Acapulco  |    33   |
   +------------+------------+---------+
   | 2021-01-07 |  Acapulco  |    42   |
   +------------+------------+---------+
   | 2021-01-08 |  Acapulco  |    66   |
   +------------+------------+---------+
   | 2021-01-09 |  Acapulco  |    17   |
   +------------+------------+---------+
   | 2021-01-10 |  Acapulco  |    18   |
   +------------+------------+---------+
   | 2021-01-11 |  Acapulco  |    13   |
   +------------+------------+---------+
   | 2021-01-12 |  Acapulco  |    55   |
   +------------+------------+---------+
```

Necesito ordenarla así para poderla imprimir en una tabla en php para mostrarla en un sitio web

```
   +----+--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
   |year|En|Feb|Mar|Abr|May|Jun|Jul|Ags|Oct|Nov|Dic|    
   +----+--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
   |2017|10| 13| 15| 66| 10| 33| 42| 66| 17| 18| 13|
   +----+--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
   |2018|10| 13| 15| 66| 10| 33| 42| 66| 17| 18| 13|
   +----+--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
   |2019|10| 13| 15| 66| 10| 33| 42| 66| 17| 18| 13|
   +----+--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
   |2020|10| 13| 15| 66| 10| 33| 42| 66| 17| 18| 13|
   +----+--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
   |2021|10| 13| 15| 66| 10| 33| 42| 66| 17| 18| 13|
   +----+--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

He investigado pero no comprendo del todo las sub consultas, si pueden orientarme se los agradesco.

Hasta el momento he intentado hacerlo con CASE pero creo no entiendo muy bien el concepto

```
SELECT YEAR(fecha) as year,
(CASE WHEN left(fecha,7)='2017' THEN TRUNCATE (AVG(pml_mda),2) ELSE '' END) AS'1',
(CASE WHEN left(fecha,4)='2018' THEN TRUNCATE (AVG(pml_mda),2) ELSE '' END) AS'2',
(CASE WHEN left(fecha,4)='2019' THEN TRUNCATE (AVG(pml_mda),2) ELSE '' END) AS'3',
(CASE WHEN left(fecha,4)='2020' THEN TRUNCATE (AVG(pml_mda),2) ELSE '' END) AS'4',
(CASE WHEN left(fecha,4)='2021' THEN TRUNCATE (AVG(pml_mda),2) ELSE '' END) AS'5'
FROM load_zone_prom
group by YEAR(fecha)
```

el resultado que obtengo es
[image]
Mi intencion es obtener algo asi en PHP
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Para que podamos ayudarte, debes enviarnos el código de lo que has intentado. No se trata de darte peces, sino de enseñarte a pescar... y, para ello, necesitamos saber qué sabes para decirte lo que aún no sabes

Comment: Corrijo la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo muy bien porqué haces medias. Tal vez necesites cambiar `SUM` por `AVG`, pero prueba con esto:

```
SELECT ano,
  SUM(CASE when mes=1 THEN pml else 0 END) Ene,
  SUM(CASE when mes=2 THEN pml else 0 END) Feb,
  SUM(CASE when mes=3 THEN pml else 0 END) Mar,
  SUM(CASE when mes=4 THEN pml else 0 END) Abr,
  SUM(CASE when mes=5 THEN pml else 0 END) May,
  SUM(CASE when mes=6 THEN pml else 0 END) Jun,
  SUM(CASE when mes=7 THEN pml else 0 END) Jul,
  SUM(CASE when mes=8 THEN pml else 0 END) Ago,
  SUM(CASE when mes=9 THEN pml else 0 END) Sep,
  SUM(CASE when mes=10 THEN pml else 0 END) Oct,
  SUM(CASE when mes=11 THEN pml else 0 END) Nov,
  SUM(CASE when mes=12 THEN pml else 0 END) Dic
  FROM (
    SELECT YEAR(fecha) ano,
      MONTH(fecha) mes,
      SUM(pml) pml
      FROM load_zone_prom
      GROUP BY 1,2  
  ) c1
  GROUP BY 1;
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios y seguimos iterando hasta dar con ello.

Comment: Quedo perfecto y efectivamente era AVG muchas gracias

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿por qué promedios? ¿Qué representan esos números? ¿Lluvia diaria? [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Comment: Son los Precios Marginales Locales de la energia en México, es una como se cobra la Energia en mexico, depende de la zona o del nodop para calcular los costos, con estas graficas conocemos cual es la hora mas barata de la energia y l amas costosa asi como el comportamiento del mercado mayorista